# Group Concat in Redshift

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, amazon-redshift

I have a table like this:

```
| Col1       | Col2        |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |        a;b; |    
| 1          |        b;c; |
| 2          |        c;d; |
| 2          |        d;e; |
```

I want the result to be some thing like this.

```
| Col1       | Col2        |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |       a;b;c;|
| 2          |       c;d;e;|
```

Is there some way to write a set function which adds unique values in a column into an array and then displays them. I am using the Redshift Database which mostly uses postgresql with the following difference:
[Unsupported PostgreSQL Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at Redshift's [`listagg()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) function which is similar to MySQL's `group_concat`. You would need to split the items first and then use `listagg()` to give you a list of values. Do take note, though, that, as the documentation states:

> LISTAGG does not support DISTINCT expressions
>
> (**Edit: As of 11th October 2018, `DISTINCT` is now supported.** See [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html).)

So will have to take care of that yourself. Assuming you have the following table set up:

```
create table _test (col1 int, col2 varchar(10));
insert into _test values (1, 'a;b;'), (1, 'b;c;'), (2, 'c;d;'), (2, 'd;e;');
```

### Fixed number of items in `Col2`

Perform as many `split_part()` operations as there are items in `Col2`:

```
select
    col1
  , listagg(col2, ';') within group (order by col2)
from (
        select col1, split_part(col2, ';', 1) as col2 from _test
  union select col1, split_part(col2, ';', 2) as col2 from _test
)
group by col1
;
```

### Varying number of items in `Col2`

You would need a helper here. If there are more rows in the table than items in `Col2`, a workaround with `row_number()` could work (but is expensive for large tables):

```
with _helper as (
    select
        (row_number() over())::int as part_number
    from
        _test
),
_values as (
    select distinct
        col1
      , split_part(col2, ';', part_number) as col2
    from
        _test, _helper
    where
        length(split_part(col2, ';', part_number)) > 0
)
select
    col1
  , listagg(col2, ';') within group (order by col2) as col2
from
    _values
group by
    col1
;
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I just wanted to point out that according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html LISTAGG supports DISTINCT expressions now.

Comment: Thanks @Yerke, I've added this note to my answer.