# Getting a list of subsequence values in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following scenario and I am not sure if it is possible to implement it using SQL.

| UID | PID | Event | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 323 | 1 | A | 10:01 |
| 323 | 1 | B | 10:02 |
| 323 | 1 | C | 10:03 |
| 323 | 1 | D | 10:04 |
| 321 | 3 | A | 10:03 |
| 321 | 3 | B | 10:04 |
| 321 | 3 | C | 10:05 |

I need to get the subsequence of events following the event 'B' so the result will be something like :

| UID | PID | list of events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 323 | 1 | C,D |
| 321 | 3 | C |

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this for MySQL and have a fiddler example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee6809/12

```
SELECT
   UID, a.PID, GROUP_CONCAT(EVENT)
FROM 
TableName AS a
LEFT Join (SELECT PID, eventtime FROM TableName WHERE event = 'B') b on a.PID = b.PID
WHERE a.eventtime > b.eventtime
GROUP BY UID, PID
```

Which would be the general concept for me. But redshift doesn't have GROUP_CONCAT so looking at this other post I think you can use listagg [Group Concat in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365534/group-concat-in-redshift)